# How to change snap channel for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have installed IntelliJ IDEA by using snap, and I've installed edge version:
`sudo snap install intellij-idea-ultimate --edge --classic`

Current status:

```
$ snap list 
Name                    Version            Rev   Tracking  Developer      Notes
atom                    1.27.2             159   stable    snapcrafters   classic
core                    16-2.33            4830  stable    canonical      core
intellij-idea-ultimate  2018.2-EAP         56    edge      jetbrains      classic
...
```

How to replace the edge version with the stable version, without break current project settings and break license?

Comment: Project settings are stored in the .idea directory inside your project. Your license is stored in your $HOME/.IntelliJ2018/config. I doubt that changing versions would  affect any of the two.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To change channel execute

```
sudo snap refresh intellij-idea-ultimate --stable --classic
```